# NLA Editor moving tracks up or down

Tags: interface, nla-editor

Following a tutorial there should be a possibility to move tracks up or down in the NLA editor with the <kbd>Page Up</kbd> or <kbd>Page Down</kbd> keys but I can't get it to work. I tried several options with no result.
How can I change the tracks vertically?

[image]

PS: I use Blender 2.8x on Windows 10 latest updates.

Comment: weird because page up and down seems to work, maybe check your Preferences > Keymap > NLA Editor > NLA Editor (Global) > Move Strips Up...

Comment: Hi moonboots, thanks, i chequed the preferences, everything is as it should be. But also the NLA Menue doesnt have any result https://imgur.com/dwbuD4U the stripe "Walk" does not move down.

Comment: Actually you need to click on the wanted track (not the strip), then arrow up and down

Comment: Hi. In future please use the built-in uploader when adding images to questions or answers. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Hi Ray Mairlot, thanks for the info, i will do so.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it work -> Track ordering:

[image]